# Inline javascript not working with WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have this html content stored in my strings.xml

```
<string name="html">
            <![CDATA[
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        *{
                            margin: 0 0 0 0;
                            padding: 0 0 0 0;
                        }
                        body{
                            background: #000;
                            color: #FFF;
                        }
                        #content {
                            text-align: justify;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function(){

                            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Changed";
                        }
                    </script>
                    </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="content">
                        <p>Hello</p>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
            ]]></string>
```

This should change the div with id content to "Changed" and it works fine if you try it in a browser. Problem is tho, it does not work in a WebView even if we have setJavascriptEnabled(true)

Here is my activity:

```
...
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_webView1);
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

  view.loadData(getString(R.string.html), "text/html", "utf-8");
...
```

I have no idea why its not working? Any clue? :)

Comment: how are you loading the html into the webview?

Comment: if you put the onload statement in the body tag does it work? as in, <body onload="yourFunction()" />

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with HTML that had inline javascript not working in a `WebView` loaded via `loadData` with the console error kept saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier
```

Turns out the problem was with my inline javascript syntax being too loose, you **must** be strict with your end-of-line markers, `;`.

For example, this is broken:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var x = 'sd'
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Where as THIS works:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var x = 'sd';
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Notice the addition of 2 semi-colons, both are required to fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are loading the html using view.loadData(), did you know you can pass javascript to loadUrl() and it will execute directly? Also, have you checked to make sure the string is arriving in that method exactly as you want it?
Is it doing anything at all in your current approach? I would suggest starting with a simpler string and see if it does what you expect. loadData() is a little weird about executing javascript. Somethings that work from within other browsers just don't work with webview via loadData().